# Resize Replace logo Function clashing with navigation

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

So I'm a graphic designer with next to no coding knowledge, and want to learn. My friend and partner who is a web developer is away.

I am trying to replace a logo on our responsive site when the dimensions are under a certain amount of pixels or when a mobile view is displayed.

Got half of it working, on scroll down but then when adding this bit to try and have resize of browser which changes the navigation bar, the nav bar misbehaves and becomes a big static block.

Tried firebug and got stuck.

```
 $(window).resize(function()
    { if($( window ).width()<750){ img.src = img.dataset.scroll; // set the scroll image 
    }
    else
    { img.src = img.dataset.orig; // set the original image back 
    } 
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't use javascript for this, but css `@media` queries: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries